# Permissions after swapping NAS drives

Tags: linux, backup, nas, file-permissions, rsync

I’ll start with a list of facts:
I had a 1gb drive connected to my NAS.
I use rsync to backup a /folder with many subdirectories for a server (bbs software) in which the permissions and file attributes are needed for the software to run properly.
I upgraded my NAS drive to a 4GB.
When copying over the old backup driveS, some permissions got changed.

My question:
Is there a way to use Rsync (or otherwise) to fix ALL the permissions for /folder, all of its subdirectories and every file within?

For all I know, rsync does this automatically at the next backup.. however if not, is there a way to do this?

In the worst case, I’ll have to re-backup about 400gb. Ugh.

Thanks a ton, internet.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for rsync will list all options available on your system.  You probably want to use something along the lines of `rsync -av --progress /src /dest` which will preserve ownership and perms, be verbose and show progress

> -a, --archive
> This is equivalent to -rlptgoD. It is a quick way  of  saying  you  want  recursion  and  want  to
> preserve  almost  everything  (with -H being a notable omission).  The only exception to the above
> equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied.

You can also recursively change the owner and permissions of the destination after the fact with
`chown -R` and `chmod -R`